# Prohibit addtionnal attributes in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible to prohibit attributes other than those provided ?

Example : for node person, I define `name`attribute only. Is it possible to prohibit others attributes to be inserted in the xml to be checked ?

```
<person name="smith" size="15" foo="bar">
</person>
```

Trigger an error on `size`and `foo` because other attributes than `name` are not allowed.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please supply your xsd, and we should be able to help.

Comment: If you define that one attribute you are not allowing any others by default, so I am not sure what the problem is (unless it is about stuff like `xml:lang`).